# Truncate output of Hugging Face pipeline for Facebook/Opt LLM to one word

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I'm working with Hugging Face's pipeline module to perform text generation with the `facebook/opt` model. Ideally, I would like the model to only output one word: the expected next word, given the input string.

Currently, my code looks something like this:

```
from transformers import pipeline
generator = pipeline('text-generation', model="facebook/opt-1.3b")

generate_input = "This is a"
generate_length = (len(generate_input.split()) * 2) + 5
generate_output = generator(generate_input, max_length=generate_length)
```

Note: I specify `max_length`, because if I do not, I get a warning when I pass in large input strings.

Obviously, I can remove any excess output after the fact, but my goal would be to provide arguments such that the pipeline model only outputs the single next word. This is because theoretically reducing the amount of output reduces the number of predictions, in turn reducing the computation time. So how can I tell the pipeline to only output the single next word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is the [max_new_tokens](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/text_generation#transformers.GenerationConfig.max_new_tokens) parameter:

```py
from transformers import pipeline
generator = pipeline('text-generation', model="facebook/opt-1.3b")

generate_input = "This is a"
generate_output = generator(generate_input, max_new_tokens=1)
print(generate_output)
```

Output:

```
[{'generated_text': 'This is a great'}]
```

Please note that token!=word. That means depending on your model you might want to use different values and perform a post-processing.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect! I initially ran into [this issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/21369), but was able to fix it by upgrading my version of transformers.